# using jquery effects on a div that has been .load()'ed in

Tags: jquery, load

I have some jQuery effects (`slideUp()`, etc.) that work just fine.

Now I `.load()` after a `setTimeout` the div in there and the effects no longer work.

This is because the div's didn't exist before the `.load()` I presume.

The effects and the `.load()` are both in the same JS file and are all wrapped in `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { /*They are here*/ });`

How can I invoke those effects on those divs after the are `.load()`'ed in?

Comment: you might need `.live()` for dynamic stuff http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @tq - `.live()` has been deprecated and should never be recommended any more.  `.on()` or `.delegate()` are the replacements.  Without seeing the actual code the OP is asking about, it is not possible to tell whether this is the issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post the code setting the .slideUp() method etc.  I'm assuming you have something like this:

```
$(function) () {

   $('.class').slideUp(300);
   $('.wrapper').load('someurl.html'); // this loads some elements with .class
   // these elements won't get slideUp applied because they are not in the DOM at the time of the slideUp call


)};
```

You need to set the events/functions in the load call back:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  //apply events to new elements
  $('.class').slideUp(300);  // this would be inside a click event I'm assuming
});
```

Or as mentioned in the comments... You can (should) be using .on which can handle delegation.  My point is to try and help you understand why the events are not applied

Comment: Well this answer works for me right now - so I'll accept it when I'm allowed to - thanks!

Comment: -however, I will look into using `.on`